# Copy the entire based on conditional statement

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm comparing two sheets based on the second column of each one. If I found that there is some missing values, I copying the corresponding row from sheet1 to sheet2. My script is running perfectly however I'm copying each cell one by one. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to deal with this. I would like to copy and pass the full row directly.

My question will make more sense if you're looking at my code, especially the last part :

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var date1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues(); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
var date2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < date1.length; i++){
      test = sheet2.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue()
      test1 = sheet1.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue()
      if (test != test1 ) {
  var data1 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,2).getValue();
  var data2 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,3).getValues();
  var data3 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,4).getValue();
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(data1);
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(data2);
  sheet2.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue(data3);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Copy Row Ranges

This should get you what you want.

```
function copyRowRanges() 
{
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var date1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues(); 
var date2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < date1.length; i++)
  {
      test = sheet2.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue()
      test1 = sheet1.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue()
      if (test != test1 ) 
      {
        var rng1Array = sheet1.getRange(i+1,2,1,3).getValues();
        sheet2.getRange(i+1,2,1,3).setValues(rng1Array);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting and setting values individually, you can get arrays of data.  Then build a new array of data and set all the values at once.  I have not tested this, but you should be able to see the basic logic for how to accomplish this by studying the code.  There may be changes that you need to make, or errors.  I've basically done all the work for you and rewritten your code.

```
function myFunction() {
  var arrayNewData,arrayOneRowOfData,array_1_Columns_2_to_4,array_2_Columns_2_to_4,
      data1,data2,data3,date1_Array,date2_Array,
      i,L,sheet1,sheet2,thisValue1,thisValue2;

  arrayOneRowOfData = [];
  arrayNewData = [];

  sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  date1_Array = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  date2_Array = sheet2.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();

  array_1_Columns_2_to_4 = sheet1.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
  array_2_Columns_2_to_4 = sheet2.getRange(1, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();

  L = date1_Array.length;

  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    thisValue1 = date1_Array[i][0];
    thisValue2 = date2_Array[i][0];

    //Must get value no matter what because can not have
    //empty cells or good values will be overwritten with empty cells
    data1 = array_1_Columns_2_to_4[i][0];
    data2 = array_1_Columns_2_to_4[i][1];
    data3 = array_1_Columns_2_to_4[i][2];

    arrayOneRowOfData = [];//reset

    if (thisValue1 !== thisValue2 ) {     
      arrayOneRowOfData.push(data1);
      arrayOneRowOfData.push(data2);
      arrayOneRowOfData.push(data3);

    } else {//Values are equal but the new array must still get values
      arrayOneRowOfData.push(array_2_Columns_2_to_4[i][0]);
      arrayOneRowOfData.push(array_2_Columns_2_to_4[i][1]);
      arrayOneRowOfData.push(array_2_Columns_2_to_4[i][2]);

    }

    arrayNewData.push(arrayOneRowOfData);//push inner array representing one row into outer array
  }

  sheet2.getRange(1, 2, arrayNewData.length, 3).setValue(arrayNewData);//Write all values in one operation
}
```